# problem in and lparam in sendmessage(delphi)

Tags: delphi

i want to move the mouse using *WM_MOUSEMOVE* message.but i do not know how to set *lparam* value?
please guide to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
procedure MouseMove(x,y:Integer); 
Begin
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE or MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, x, y, 0, 0);
End;
```

Bye;

Answer (score 5):

WM_MOUSEMOVE is just a notification - it is sent as a result of a mouse moving, it does not cause it to happen.

[SetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648394(VS.85).aspx) can move the cursor to a new position.  [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx) can be used to simulate mouse events directly.